# Define two variables with same parameters

Tags: javascript, json, owl-carousel

Is there a way to define two variables with same parameters, so I don't have to repeat code?

```
 var owl_first = $('.owl-carousel-first');
 var owl_second = $('.owl-carousel-second');
```

This will just repeat for both (if I don't define them separately Owl carousel doesn't work).

```
 owl_first.owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  margin:30,
  nav:false,
  dots: false,
  autoplay:true,
  autoplayTimeout:5000,
  autoplayHoverPause:true,
  responsive:{
    0:{
      items:1
    },
    600:{
      items:3
    } 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `,` while selecting multiple elements(Also known as [*Multiple Selector*](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/))

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel-first,.owl-carousel-second');
owl.owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 30,
  nav: false,
  dots: false,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 5000,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    }
  }
})
```

*Note:* You will have to initialize the *widget* for both the `elements` to make `owlCarousel` work!

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to define multiple variables without having to write var before each of them, you can go

```
var owl_first = $('.owl-carousel-first'),
    owl_second= = $('owl-carousel-second');
```

If you want to have multiple jQuery selectors, you can follow what Rayon said.